# Is it possibile to concatenate with bidimensional arrayformula?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I have a table like this:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Photo1-1 | Photo1-2 | Photo1-3 |          |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Photo2-1 | Photo2-2 |          |          |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Photo3-1 | Photo3-2 | Photo3-3 | Photo3-4 |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

And I need to output concatenate values in a column like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http:/www.domain.com/photo/Photo1-1|http:/www.domain.com/photo/Photo1-2|http:/www.domain.com/photo/Photo1-3|                                      |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http:/www.domain.com/photo/Photo2-1|http:/www.domain.com/photo/Photo2-2|                                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| http:/www.domain.com/photo/Photo3-1|http:/www.domain.com/photo/Photo3-2|http:/www.domain.com/photo/Photo3-3|http:/www.domain.com/photo/Photo3-4| |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm using this formula:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E2));arrayformula(CONCATENATE(IF(NOT(ISBLANCK('inventario ebay'!Y5:AC5));
 'inventario ebay'!$Z$2 & 'inventario ebay'!Y5:AC5 & "|";"")));"")
```

But I would like to use ArrayFormula or something else so I don't need copy/paste it in every cell.

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41847717/) is possible to do it with this formula (a little modified to suite my question):

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(query(transpose("http:/www.domain.com/photo/"&A1:D3&"|"),,50000)))
```

Comment: the only thing that remain is the "space" among results? 

I would like: A2B2C2D2E2F2G2H2, instead of A2 B2 C2 D2 E2 F2 G2 H2

Answer (score 0):

**CELL A1: `=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(JOIN(""; 'inventario ebay'!A2:H2))))` 

THEN SELECT A1 AND: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>**+**<kbd>DOWN ARROW</kbd>** **...** **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>**+**<kbd>ENTER</kbd>**